# Hibernate - Foreign key is empty while using mappedBy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've 2 tables `Employee` & `Vehicle`, where one employee can have multiple vehicles.
Below is the mapping that I've defined:

**Employee.java**

```
@Entity(name = "emp_details")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int empId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="employee")
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public List<Vehicle> getVehicles() {
        return vehicles;
    }

    public void setVehicles(List<Vehicle> vehicles) {
        this.vehicles = vehicles;
    }

}
```

**Vehicle.java**

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int vehicleId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="empId")
    private Employee employee;

    private String name;

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public int getVehicleId() {
        return vehicleId;
    }

    public void setVehicleId(int vehicleId) {
        this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**Main class**

```
public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee emp = new Employee();

        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
        vehicle.setName("Honda");
        emp.getVehicles().add(vehicle);


        SessionFactory sFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(emp);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(sFactory.getSessionFactoryOptions().getServiceRegistry());

    }

}
```

But when I execute this, Vehicle.employee_id is empty. I was expecting that my foreign key will be inserted there.

[image]

What am I missing?

Thank You

Comment: You should not cascade from vehicle to employee. Always cascade in only one direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show us the code that persists your entities, but my guess is that you are not setting the `employee` to the `vehicle`.

You need to manage both sides of bidirectional entity relationship. Your code should look something like this

```
employee.getVehicles().add(vehicle);
vehicle.setEmployee(employee);

session.save(employee);
```

**UPDATE:**

In this case, `Vehicle` is the owning side of the relation because the foreign key is in its database table. You just added the new vehicle to the employee's list of vehicles. When you `save` the employee, there's nothing to change in `Employee`s database, and the `save` operation cascades to `Vehicle`. Vehicle does not have its employee set, it is null, so it puts `null` in `empId` column

Bottom line, you have to make sure both sides of bidirectional relationship are wired up correctly.

Comment: As I suspected in my answer. Add `vehicle.setEmployee(emp)` before you save the employee.

Comment: So you are saying, apart from saving vehicle in employee, I also need to save employee in vehicle. But I thought Hibernate was intelligent enough to create the relationship if it is defined in just one way. Please elaborate for me is possible. Thank You.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope it makes it more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bidirectional relationship you have to 
set the relation on both sides.

That means you have to set the `employee` for your `vehicle` also.

You can do this by calling

```
vehicle.setEmployee(emp);
```

and then store or update your entity (if it's not attached to session already).

Usually to set a bidirectional relationship you provide special methods in your entities.

```
public class Vehicle {
    ...
    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
        employee.addVehicle(this)
    }
    ...
}

public class Employee {
    ...
    public void addVehicle(Vehicle v) {
          if(!vehicles.contains(v)) {
             vehicles.add(v);
          }
          if(!this.equals(v.getEmployee()) {
             v.setEmployee(this);
          }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think need to edit your code. you miss the entity jpa rule. you can some search jpa entity. you read description for you. link : [enter link description here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/index.htm)

(Modified your Employee.java)

```
@Entity(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idx;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "employee")
    private List<Vehicle> vehicle = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

(Modified your Vehicle.java)

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idx;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="employee_id")
    private Employee employee;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Employee entity class, you haven't used @Column annotation on empId. In Vehicle class you are referencing Employee using @JoinColumn(name="employee_id"),so column **employee_id** must exist in emp_details table. So you need to modify your Employee class to something with

```
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     @Column(name="employee_id")
     private int empId;
```

Comment: No. That's not right. The employee_id is in the vehicle table and references to the id in the employee table. It should not be in the employee table.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to cascade onetoMany from Employee Entity

Comment: How do you persist your data?