# Hibernate not setting foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to learn Hibernate with this simple example but I'm having so trouble with the foreign key which remains "null" in the database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb1")
public class Track {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_tb1", unique= true)
    private int id_tb1;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_tb2")
    private tb2 cd;
```

And this is the second class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb2")
public class CD {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_tb2", unique = true)
    private int id_tb2;
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "cd")
    private List<tb1> tracks = new ArrayList<tb1>();
```

I save like this:

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
                Session session1 = factory.openSession();
                session1.beginTransaction();
                session1.save(tb2);
                session1.getTransaction().commit();
```

but when Isavethe id_tb2 (in the table tb1) is not set and it remains null. What I'm missing?

Comment: What type of list is tracks in CD class. tb1? add your entire code.

Comment: I assume its  private List<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<Track>(); in CD class instead of private List<tb1> tracks = new ArrayList<tb1>();

Comment: @RohitGaikwad yes!

Comment: can't you call it `cd` & `track` instead of `tb1` and `tb2`? it is making the picture messy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have to set the relation on both sides for a bidirectional relationship.

So you have to set your relationship for`CD` and your `Track` object and persist/merge them afterwards.

Without seeing to much of your code you have to do something like.

```
cd.getTracks().add(track);
track.setCD(cd);
session1.save(track);
session1.save(cd);
```

See [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891442/hibernate-foreign-key-is-empty-while-using-mappedby/38895169#38895169) for more details.

Comment: Thank you man! I already had the method setTb2 but when I was saving the object tb2 in the database i wasn't calling it, so that was the problem!

Comment: You also can use the cascade annotation to persist or merge the related entity implicitly see https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/03/05/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/ for more information.

Comment: in order to have the FK populated in DB, you only need the side owning the relationship to be populated.  (However you should still make both side populated not because of Hibernate, but just because of consistency in entities)

Answer (score 1):

I think your type of the table2

```
private tb2 cd;
```

should be changed as

```
private CD cd;
```

Comment: thats a nice catch

Comment: I don't believe that this is the error. Because if it was the code won't even compile. But that's not the problem OP is facing.